DataStax Cassandra C# Driver Exception - Excepted ResultResponse, obtained Cassandra.Responses.SupportedResponse
I am getting a strange exception from the ISession Execute() method:
Excepted ResultResponse, obtained Cassandra.Responses.SupportedResponse
// "Excepted" typo is intentional - copied straight from the source
Stack Trace: 
at Cassandra.Requests.RequestExecution.ValidateResult(Response response) 
at Cassandra.Requests.RequestExecution.HandleRowSetResult(Response response) 
at Cassandra.Requests.RequestExecution.HandleResponse(IRequestError error, Response response, Host host)

This is getting thrown by a call to Session.Execute() that is being called nearly constantly many times per second in a Dockerized webservice. It is rare, and appears to coincide with elevated rates of timeouts sometimes, but does not occur with every single timeout, just once or twice during a given burst of timeouts.
I cannot find anything about a "SupportedResponse" in the DataStax C# driver, except this stub from version 2.7.1:  https://www.fuget.org/packages/CassandraCSharpDriver/2.7.1/lib/net40/Cassandra.dll/Cassandra/SupportedResponse
But I am using version 3.22.0 (and .NET7 if that matters).
I'd rather not have to do something like
var response = Session.Execute(...);
if (typeof(response) == typeof(SupportedResponse))
{
    ...
}

But if this is a known issue that I have to work around for now, I'll probably have to.
Most of the code related to this proprietary/confidential, but I can put together a generic example if needed.
Thanks in advance!
